# Struts2 + Log4j2

Tags: java, struts2, log4j2

I'm developing a `Struts2` webapp and I set up the logger. In the official documentation there is only the configuration for `log4j`, but nothing about `log4j2`. I started looking around and seems that `Struts2` does not support `log4j2`. But the last question I've found is this one:

[Log4j2.0 is not working with Jboss 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834646/log4j2-0-is-not-working-with-jboss-5)

> Struts2 doesn't support Log4j 2.0 right now, there are plans to add support for it during upcoming strutsathon.opensource.io

Since this question was answered in 2013, Struts2 still doesn't support `Log4j2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are lucky! In the latest version (`2.3.24`), as you can see in the [Releas Notes](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?version=12331974&projectId=12311041), it has been added:

> #### New feature
>
> - [[WW-4492](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4492)]- Add support for Log4J2 as a struts and xwork logging backend

Comment: Thanks Andrea, any suggestions for using log files rather than log to console?

Comment: Last two lines: https://struts.apache.org/docs/logging.html#Logging-Definingwhichfactorytouse